# Which graph should I use for this ?

Tags: data-visualisation

In order to teach a game to kids, I would like to make a chart. Since english is not my mother language, I'm just asking for the proper name of the template I should use to display my data.

It's a construction game, with tons of raw materials, you collect it at a cost. i.e. : wood, stone, metals, etc.

You can use this raw material to make other precious materials, such as boards, tools, houses, roads... and so forth, those materials can also be combined to make others stuffs. Production costs should be aggregated. it's the main point of the visualization.

What is the type of graph I can use in order to represent the multiple combinaisons between materials ? I should look like a tree I guess. But not quite the same. It seems like a rather simple question, but I cannot figure out which kind of template I should look for.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Are you looking for a [circle graph](https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+graph&num=20&safe=off&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=v3-YVJHaLIajgwTcr4CIAQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=955)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with **Tree**. Really it's not a graph you're after at all. It's some sort of **Chart**.

[Tree Structure on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) provides a basic idea of this concept. You might also look at the terms Flow Chart, Organizational Chart, or Hierarchy Chart like this one:

[image]

If you want to incorporate the numeric values you'll have to come up with some more complex charting specific to your needs. This could take on a lot of different concepts to offer anything concrete to you.

Something that might help is looking at how games like [Alchemy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.zed_0xff.android.alchemy&hl=en) or [Skyrim](http://www.elderscrolls.com/skyrim) handle construction either in-game or at online guides.

One website presents Skyrim Alchemy recipes like this:

[image]

Or here's a picture of in-game Blacksmithing from Skyrim. You can see under "Falmer Helmer" it says the stats, and below that it says the ingredients and quantity required to produce it:

[image]

There's a nice table chart of all Smithing at http://www.carlsguides.com/walkthroughs/skyrim/combat/smithing.php:

[image]